# How to add epochs to Keras network in scikit-learn pipeline

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network, pipeline

I am using code from this website to help me analyze tweets, it is using a pipeline: 
https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-text-classification-in-python-using-spacy/

```
# Create our list of punctuation marks
punctuations = string.punctuation

# Create our list of stopwords
nlp = spacy.load('en')
stop_words = spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS

# Load English tokenizer, tagger, parser, NER and word vectors
parser = English()

# Creating our tokenizer function
def spacy_tokenizer(sentence):
    # Creating our token object, which is used to create documents with linguistic annotations.
    mytokens = parser(sentence)

    # Lemmatizing each token and converting each token into lowercase
    mytokens = [ word.lemma_.lower().strip() if word.lemma_ != "-PRON-" else word.lower_ for word in mytokens ]

    # Removing stop words
    mytokens = [ word for word in mytokens if word not in stop_words and word not in punctuations ]

    # return preprocessed list of tokens
    return mytokens


# Custom transformer using spaCy
class predictors(TransformerMixin):
    def transform(self, X, **transform_params):
        # Cleaning Text
        return [clean_text(text) for text in X]

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

    def get_params(self, deep=True):
        return {}

# Basic function to clean the text
def clean_text(text):
    # Removing spaces and converting text into lowercase
    return text.strip().lower()


bow_vector = CountVectorizer(tokenizer = spacy_tokenizer, ngram_range=(1,1))

x = tweets['text']
Y = tweets['target']
x_train, x_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(x, Y, test_size = 0.2)

#This part I figured out on my own:

from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
classifier = Sequential()
#First Hidden Layer
classifier.add(Dense(500, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal', input_dim=19080))
#Second  Hidden Layer
classifier.add(Dense(500, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
#Output Layer
classifier.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))

classifier.compile(optimizer ='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics =['accuracy'])
# Create pipeline using Bag of Words
pipe = Pipeline([("cleaner", predictors()),
                 ('vectorizer', bow_vector),
                 ('classifier', classifier)])

# model generation
pipe.fit(x_train, Y_train)
```

My problem is, I want to do this:

```
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train, batch_size=5, epochs=200)
```

But I cannot seem to make it work with the pipeline. I can run it without that and it runs great with only one epoch. But I'm pretty sure I'd get better accuracy with more epochs than just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a scikit-learn wrapper:

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

def create_network():
    network = Sequential()
    network.add(Dense(500, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal', input_dim=19080))
    network.add(Dense(500, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
    network.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))

    network.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
                    optimizer='adam', 
                    metrics=['accuracy']) 

    return network

classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_network, 
                                 epochs=10, 
                                 batch_size=100, 
                                 verbose=0)
```

and use the `classifier` shown above in your pipeline, in which you can define both `epochs` and `batch_size`.